# Python: How to vectorize function for a dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, vectorization

How can i use pandas vectorization or use numpy vectorization that involves generating/building a dictionary?  So currently, I just implemented iterating through the data from using `df.itertuples`.  Was wondering if I can optimize it using pandas vectorization but I get an error of `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` or `'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`.  Which I totally understand why, since they are mutable objects.  But how can I implement a below like example using pandas or numpy vectorization?  Is it even possible? And even if it is, would it even make any difference in performance?

Lets consider a simple code where it iterates through the dataframe then gathers data that occurred until that row:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

FILENAME = "data.csv"

class Group():
    def __init__(self):
        self.symbol = None
        self.groups = defaultdict(int)

    def update(self, order, symbol, group, quantity):
        self.groups[group] += quantity

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.groups}"

def method1():
    df = pd.read_csv(FILENAME)
    data = defaultdict(Group)
    for (i, order, symbol, group, quantity) in df.itertuples():
        data[symbol].symbol = symbol
        data[symbol].update(order, symbol, group, quantity)
        print(f"Symbol {symbol} current data: {data[symbol]}")

method1()
```

Example data.csv has:

```
order,symbol,group,quantity
0,A,4,800
1,A,9,500
2,C,1,200
3,C,3,-900
4,D,7,-600
5,B,9,900
6,B,9,300
7,C,7,100
8,C,8,500
9,C,6,-900
```

Sample output:

```
Symbol A data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {4: 800})
Symbol A data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {4: 800, 9: 500})
Symbol C data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 200})
Symbol C data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 200, 3: -900})
Symbol D data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {7: -600})
Symbol B data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {9: 900})
Symbol B data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {9: 1200})
Symbol C data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 200, 3: -900, 7: 100})
Symbol C data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 200, 3: -900, 7: 100, 8: 500})
Symbol C data: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 200, 3: -900, 7: 100, 8: 500, 6: -900})
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `groupby()` would be appropriate.  The data frame `df` is defined as per `data.csv` above.

```
g = df.groupby('symbol')[['group', 'quantity']]
g.groups

{'A': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 'B': Int64Index([5, 6], dtype='int64'),
 'C': Int64Index([2, 3, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64'),
 'D': Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')}

# get keys like this:
g.groups.keys()

dict_keys(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

We can see more about a particular group; get_group('C') looks like the last line of your sample output.  Use `g.get_group('C').to_dict()` for a related version.

```
print(g.get_group('C'))
   group  quantity
2      1       200
3      3      -900
7      7       100
8      8       500
9      6      -900
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, but not sure if this will work for my example.  The problem with this one is that it will contain the group/data for the entire dataframe.  I need to be able to print the data until that current row, almost like a history of how the data gets built from row to row.  Pandas group function performs it on the entire dataframe, almost like an overall summary.  Where I need it as like a history of events almost